# composer install in post-receive in git hooks not working

Tags: php, git, deployment, composer-php, git-post-receive

I am trying to setup automatic deployment to my production server with git `post-receive`

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/cushbu.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
echo running composer
composer install -d /var/www/html/cushbu.com
echo finished
```

But the `composer install` command is not working also is there is any way to know the status the current execution post script??

i can't able to see `running composer` output in command line

**UPDATE**

I've added `cd /var/www/html/cushbu.com && composer install` but it doesn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
composer install --working-dir=/var/www/html/cushbu.com -vvv > ~/composer.log 2>&1
```

The `-vvv` flag will enable verbose output.  `> ~/composer.log 2>&1` will write this output to a `composer.log` file in your home directory.